# How to add deferred methods to a delegated event

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap my head around using deferreds for a specific application. I am not sure if I am way off here and my strategy is just wrong, or if I am simply overlooking something basic.

Let's say I have some delegated `on` events:

```
jQuery('#my-element').on('change', 'select,input', Myclass.change);
```

Essentially, what I am after (or something equivalent) would be to do:

```
jQuery('#my-element').on('change', 'select,input', Myclass.change)
    .then(Myclass.next)
    .done(Myclass.done);
```

How can I add these deferred methods to my basic delegated events?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing [$.Callbacks("once")](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/#once); `Myclass.next` , `Myclass.done` should be called exactly "once"

```js
var callbacks = $.Callbacks("once");
var Myclass = {
  "change" : function(e) {
    // do stuff within `Myclass.change`
    console.log(e.target.value, "change");
    // call `$.when()` with desired argument, e.g.,
    // with `e.target.value` , 
    // passed to `Myclass.next` , `Myclass.done`
    // Note, `.then()` can return different `promise` value
    // `.done()` returns original `promise` value
    callbacks.add(function() {
      return $.when(e.target.value).then(Myclass.next).done(Myclass.done)
    }).fire();

  }
  , "next" : function(value) {
    console.log(value, "next");
    return value
  }
  , "done" : function(value) {
    console.log(value, "done");
  }

};


jQuery('#my-element').on('change', 'select,input', Myclass.change);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="my-element">
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Good to note that `.then()` and `.done()` have some functional overlap, so OP might want to consider dropping one: `.then(doneCallback, failCallback)` is the equivalent of `.done(doneCallback).fail(failCallback)` :)

Comment: @Terry Not certain interpret _"have some functional overlap"_ correctly ? Though, did note difference between `.then()` , `.done()` - `.then()` can return different promise value , `.done()` returns original promise value - not entirely equivalent ?

Comment: So say I queue up a bunch of manually triggered `change` events, doesn't `then` and `done` get called after each individual change event? I am looking for `then` and `done` to be called just once after all queued `change` events happen.

Comment: @pspahn _"I am looking for `then` and `done` to be called just once after all queued `change` events happen"_ ? "queued `change` events" not appear at OP ? "queue" not appear  at OP ? Can include `js` where a "queue" is defined , and `change` events "triggered" ?

Comment: @pspahn Is requirement for `change` event to be called only once ?

Comment: That is correct. I want `done` to happen once after all `change` events are complete.

Comment: @pspahn Yes, that is sequence at `js` at answer . Though `change` event would be called at each `change` event. Tried substituting `.one()` for `.on()` ?

Comment: Is requirement for `Myclass.change` to continue to be called, _after_ `Myclass.next` and `Myclass.done` have been called _once_ ? That is, `Myclass.next`, `Myclass.done` are called , at most, _once_ - though `Myclass.change` is still called at subsequent `change` events ?

Comment: @guest271314 That sounds exactly right. Each `change` should run `Myclass.change` and when all the `change` events are done, call `then` or `done` (or other deferred methods) at most once each.

Comment: Can  utilize original post to call `next`, `done` at each call to `change` ; edited post to call `next` , `done` at most _"once"_ .